# .class Expected error in java

Tags: java, arrays, authentication

I get only two errors of .class expected [I am getting this error in my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RcQt.jpg)

```
String[] email= {"Sarangmemon8","Alimutaba626","Kali_denali"};
String[] pass= {"Sarang","Mujtaba","Kali"};
System.out.println("What is your name?");
String name = input.nextLine();
System.out.println("Hello! "+name +"Would you like to Login? y/n");
String ans = input.nextLine();
if(ans=="y"){

    System.out.println("Enter your Email: ");
    String username = input.nextLine(email[0][1][2]);
    System.out.println("Enter your Password: ");
    String password = input.nextLine(pass[0][1][2]);
    if(username == email[]) { 
        if (password == pass[]) {
            System.out.println("Hello Mr. " +name);

        }
        else
        System.out.println("Wrong password");
```

Comment: Compare strings with equals not with ==

Answer (score 1):

First of all i would highly recommend you to go through your concept of 
**Arrays and Objects**

1. 1st Error: 
   Your index should be specified while trying to retrieve a value from a array.
   You need to mention the index of the array if you want to compare.
2. Second Error: **String** is treated as a object in java, and while comparing with object *equals()* method is used, that's why while equating string use *.equals()* instead of *==* .

If you have anymore problem you can comment.

Answer (score 0):

`(username == email[]` - incorrect syntax. You should specify `index` value for `email` array. E.g. `email[0]`.
The same applies to `password == pass[]`

Comment: Strings can not be compared with ==